# 2008 Opel Zafira possible windscreen leak

Tags: vauxhall, opel, water-leak, zafira

A pool of water has, only today, started to form around the interior ceiling spotlight panel between the driver and passenger seats of my 2008 Zafira. It dripped on to the seats for a while after driving the car, but has since stopped; it's still raining as heavy as it was earlier. The only reason I'm thinking that it could be my windscreen is because it is sealed almost right above where this spotlight panel is situated.

There is no sunroof in the car, and the aerial is located to the rear.

My questions are:

- What exactly should I be looking for to locate the source of this
  leak?
- Is it likely to be the windscreen or should I look elsewhere?
- Is it easy to remove the spotlight panel? Should I do this to see if
  I can find the source of the leak behind it?
- If I do find the source of the leak, would I be able to temporarily
  repair it before taking it to a garage? Would Duct tape work? Perhaps
  a sealant similar to what you would use in a bathroom?

Any other information would be greatly appreciated as I imagine I haven't asked the correct questions. My knowledge of cars is fairly limited.

My main concern is due to the Zafira recalls, which my car is part of, but not getting seen until the 14th Dec. I'm worried that this leak could mess with the electrics and possibly start a fire.

Answer (score 2):

I would begin to look around your windshield molding, front and back.  Ensure the rubber is not dry rotted.  Dry rot can occur from many heat cycles (night/day) as well as ultra violet light exposure.

The spotlight mount is also a good place to check to ensure the rubber mount is nicely sealed against the body of the car.

If water can into the body, during rain or from condensation, between the interior and the body itself it can condensate and begin to buildup.

I had this happen with a VW Rabbit 30 years ago and I fixed it by replacing my windshield molding and drying out the space by using a blow drier.

This is a possible cause to the issue.